# django-nose collect-only runs tests

Tags: python, django, testing, django-nose

Nose and django-nose installed, when the following is ran:

```
./manage.py test --collect-only
```

The following is output:

```
nosetests --collect-only --verbosity=1
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Why is `collect-only` running the tests instead of outputting their names?

Comment: I think the tests are not running. Look at the total time they executed, it's 0.000s. if you remove the --collect-only attribute, the total time changes, because they are really executed in this case.
The confusions it's because nosetests use the same output when they indeed run the tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing the verbosity seems to produce desired results:

./manage.py test --collect-only --verbosity=2

Comment: Stuff like this is the reason I hate nose.  py.test just works, without the wonky behavior.